# "-one" and "-ino" forms, what about those words that basically has suffixes "-one" or "-ino" by their own?

Tags: grammar

In Italian "-one" suffix makes the noun as "big one" and "-ino" makes it "small one"; What about those words that basically has suffixes "-one" or "-ino" by their own such as *torrone*? Is there any exception that doesn't follow this rule?

Comment: Why do you think it means small tower?

Comment: Because here it says: " Un torrone non e una torre grande, ma un dolce natalizio" ! Does it still imply that it's still a big tower?!

Comment: Have a look at my answer please

Comment: Where is “here”?

Comment: Anyway, “Un torrone non **è** una torre grande, ma un dolce natalizio” means that a *torrone* is *not* a large tower (and even less a small tower), even if it might superficially seem so.

Comment: If the question is just “what does *torrone* mean”, it can be answered by any dictionary, even an English monolingual one. If it really is “why torrone means small tower”, it is simply nonsensical.

Comment: @DaG - it appears that OP was taken in by the word "dolce".

Comment: "Torrone" is a Christmas candy made with sugar, honey and toasted almonds, but the origin of the word has nothing in common with "torre" (tower); instead it maybe derives from "torrere" which is to toast" in reference to one of its ingredients. 
See here for other possible explanations:
http://www.etimo.it/?term=torrone

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: "To toast" is said "torrar" in Catalan and we Catalans have also "torrons" as a typical Christmas dessert.

Comment: And just for completeness, a big tower is a *torrione*.

Comment: Oh! No! I was busy today since morning, that was why I couldn't seek the comments or answers, sorry. And by "here" I meant "Espresso" book.

Comment: Why was the answer deleted?

Comment: @DaG: Because it says "put on hold as off-topic by DaG, Charo♦ 7 hours ago"?! did you hold it as off-topic?!

Comment: @Gio: I think there is no necessity to delete your answer. I have "undeleted" it since other people voted to do that.

Comment: @Armin: We put your question "on hold as off-topic" because, in the way it's stated now, it makes no sense. But maybe you may reword your post so as to ask something with sense and that is not simply "what's the meaning of torrone?", which can be easily solved looking at a dictionary.

Comment: @Charo You're right, but I mentioned that was an exception to -one form in Espresso book, because now I know it's completely another word meaning a candy.

Comment: Dear @Charo, Now I edited the question to an informing question, so that other students like me learn about it. So, would you release it from being "on-hold as off topic"? Thanks

Comment: @Armin: Indeed, there are words whose termination happens to be “-one” or “-ino” without their denoting augmentative or diminutive terms. What about it?

Comment: @DaG : This way all those students like me, would NOT conclude that each "-one" suffix is necessarily augmentative and each "-ino" is necessarily diminutive!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no “exceptions” because there is no “rule”.

And the “rule” not being such works both ways: there are many words you can't affix *-one* to to mean a big specimen, unless jocularly (*pane* is “bread”, but no one would say seriously *panone*); and there are many, many words that end in *-one* without implying that there is the big version of something, but just happen to end in *-one*, like the above mentioned *torrone*, and *mattone*, *bottone*, *furgone*, *montone*, *ottone*, *canzone*, *procione*, *regione*, *cotone* and lots more.

Moreover, there are words in *-one* that *are* related to another one, but have taken a different, specific meaning: for instance a *cassetto* is a drawer, but a *cassettone* is a chest of drawers, not a big drawer; similarly with *calza* and *calzone*, *carta* e *cartone*, *santo* and *santone*, *neutro* and *neutrone* and so on. Or subtler cases where the meaning of “big” remains, but the words are nonetheless used only in some contexts, not as a generic big item of that kind: a *guantone* is used only for boxing or baseball, not for a generic big *guanto* (glove), and analogously for *tromba* and *trombone*, *tenda* e *tendone*...

All of the above, of course, also apply to *-ino*.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @DaG said (there are no rules), there are some ways to make an *accrescitivo* or *diminutivo* of words that happen to end with *-one* or *-ino*.

One technique is to use the alternative suffixes *-cione* and  *-cino*. In the case of *torrone*, the smaller version of if would be *torroncino*. Jokingly, one could also construct words like *torroncinone* (a big small *torrone*).

In other cases, to make a diminutive of a word that ends in *-ino*, one can change the suffix to *-etto* or *-uccio*. A small or young *bambino* (that is already small or young by definition), would be a *bambinetto*, for example. However, being the diminutive of something that is already small, words like these usually carry some additional context-dependant meaning.

In yet other cases, you just cannot use a suffix. For example, from the word *passione* you could construct *passioncina*, but a word like **passionona* would sound too weird (at least to my ears).